# How to get sequence number of the file in the folder?

Tags: python

I have Windows PC. My script should identify sequency number of the file passed in the command line in the folder, i.e.

```
myscript.py \\network-drive\files\Long-long.file.name.with.numbers.txt
```

Folder content is the following:

```
\\network-drive\files\
    folder1
    folder2
    file1
    file2
    Long.long.file.name.with.numbers.txt
    file3
    file4
```

My script should identify sequence number of the file given in the command line, i.e. should return 5 (folders are also to be counted; assumption is that files are sorted by their names).

**Upd**. I've stopped with the following:

```
import sys
import os.path

if sys.argv[1]: # regardless of this verification, exception happens if argument is not passed
    head, tail = os.path.split(sys.argv[1])
    print head
    print os.listdir(head)
```

The list returned by `listdir` doesn't allow me to identify what is folder and what is file. So, I can not sort them properly.

Comment: Please include in your question what have you tried.

Comment: As @IRO-bot noted, we need more info to help and will not write your script for you. What are you having trouble with: running Python scripts on Windows? Walking the folder? Parsing the filenames? Returning the value? Printing things? Sorting? Accessing network shares?

Comment: @IRO-bot, JoeFish, thanks for your comments. I've updated the question.

Comment: If you need to distinguish directories from regular files, try `os.path.isdir()` http://docs.python.org/library/os.path#os.path.isdir

Comment: I'm having a very difficult time understanding the order that those items are sorted...They're not alphabetical because in that case, `file1` would come before `folder1`.

Comment: How do you want the list sorted? Folders alphabetical first followed by files alphabetical?

Comment: @JordanMessina, yes, folders first, then files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something like this should work:

```
import os
import glob
import sys
import os.path as path

try:
    directory,file = path.split( sys.argv[1] )
    def sort_func(fname):
        """
        Russian directories , english directories, russian files then english files
        although, honestly I don't know how russian files will actually be sorted ...
        """
        fullname = path.join(directory,fname)
        isRussian = any(ord(x) > 127 for x in fullname)
        isDirectory = path.isdir(fullname)
        return ( not isDirectory, not isRussian, fullname)

    files = sorted( os.listdir(directory), key=sort_func)
    print ( files.index(file) + 1 )

except IndexError:
    print "oops, no commandline arguments"
```

Comment: Thanks. You've missed one bracket before `key`. And this code doesn't count folders. So, in my question example it will return 3 instead of 5.

Comment: `glob` definitely counts directories on Unix, but `os.listdir` is probably better.  I'll update.

Comment: Now it says `ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list`. When I checked how it works - `for fl in os.listdir(directory): print fl + ": " + str(os.path.isdir(fl))` it returns `False` even for folders.

Comment: Hopefully this try will work.  (`glob` returns the full path.  `listdir` only returns the files in the folder.  So, I needed to add the path information back into the result of `listdir`)

Comment: But if I use os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory,fl)), then it returns `True` for folders. But not sure how to apply that to `lambda`. `lambda x: (os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory,x)), x))` still returns `ValueError`.

Comment: In your attempt, you would want `files.index( file )`.  That would work too.  In fact, I like that better.  edited again.

Comment: That's interesting. Your code returned count without folder until I changed `os.path.isdir(x)` to `not os.path.isdir(x)`.

Comment: apparently i should test things before I post.  You're right.  that's because `True` => `1` and `False` => `0`, so when sorting, `False` will come *before* `True`.  My sorting was putting the directories at the end of the list, not the front. (fixed)

Comment: Looks like I've missed one point - folders and files written in Russian should go first (i.e. Folder_with_Russian_name, Folder_with_English_name, file_with_Russian_name, file_with_English_name). How can I handle it?

Comment: I have no idea.  How do you determine if a folder has an english name or a russian name?  If you can write functions to figure that out, no problem (just extend the tuple returned in the key function of sorted), but I don't know enough about Russian to make that distinction.

Comment: Looks like regex to verify if there are any other symbols than Eng and standard (like commas, numbers etc.) should help..

Comment: `ord(x)<128` can help to identify Eng characters, all others can be treated as Russian. But how to add that to the sorting?

Comment: @LA_ -- I've updated, but as I never actually need unicode in my day to day work, I don't know how unicode strings are actually sorted. (In other words, I don't know what alphabetical order is for Russian, and I don't guarantee that python does either).  I guess you'll just need to test and see ...

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems you are trying to solve, and a couple of options for the solutions.

1st - are you looking for something that is *naturally sorted* i.e.:

```
/path/to/folder/
  subfolder01/
  test1.png
  test2.png
  test3.png
  test10.png
  test11.png
```

If so...you'll need to create a natural sort method.  If you are happy with alpha-numeric sorting:

```
/path/to/folder/
  subfolder01/
  test1.png
  test10.png
  test11.png
  test2.png
  test3.png
```

Then the standard sort will work.  Depending on how you sort your files, the index of your result will vary.

To get the directory and files from the system, you can do it one of two ways - not 100% sure which is faster, so test them both out.  I'm going to break the answer into chunks so you can piece it together how best seems fit:

**Part 01: Initialization**

```
import os
import sys

try:
    searchpath = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print 'No searchpath supplied'
    sys.exit(0)

basepath, searchname = os.path.split(searchpath)
```

**Part 02: Collecting folders and files**

*Option #1: os.listdir + os.path.isfile*

```
files   = []
folders = []
for filepath in os.listdir(basepath):
    if ( os.path.isfile(filepath) ):
        files.append(filepath)
    else:
        folders.append(folder)
```

*Option #2: os.walk*

```
# we only want the top level list of folders and files,
# so break out of the loop after the first result
for basepath, folders, files in os.walk(basepath):
    break
```

**Part 03: Calculating the Index**

*Option #1: no sorting - what you get from the system is what you get*

```
# no sorting
try:
    index = len(folders) + files.index(searchname)
except IndexError:
    index = -1
```

*Option #2: alphanumeric sorting*

```
# sort alpha-numerically (only need to sort the files)
try:
    index = len(folders) + sorted(files).index(searchname)
except IndexError:
    index = -1
```

*Option #3: natural sorting*

```
# natural sort using the projex.sorting.natural method
import projex.sorting
sorted_files = sorted(files, projex.sorting.natural)
try:
    index = len(folders) + sorted_files.index(searchname)
except IndexError:
    index = -1
```

**Part 04: Logging the result**

```
# if wanting a 1-based answer
index += 1
print index
```

I'm not going to go into detail about natural sorting since that wasn't a part of the question - I think there are other forums on here you can find with advice on that.  The projex.sorting module is one that I've written and is available here: http://dev.projexsoftware.com/projects/projex if you want to see the exact implementation of it.

Suffice to say this would be the difference in results:

```
>>> import pprint, projex.sorting
>>> files = ['test2.png', 'test1.png', 'test10.png', 'test5.png', 'test11.png']
>>> print files.index('test10.png')
2
>>> print sorted(files).index('test10.png')
1
>>> print sorted(files, projex.sorting.natural).index('test10.png')
3
>>> print files
['test2.png', 'test1.png', 'test10.png', 'test5.png', 'test11.png']
>>> print sorted(files)
['test1.png', 'test10.png', 'test11.png', 'test2.png', 'test5.png']
>>> print sorted(files, projex.sorting.natural)
['test1.png', 'test2.png', 'test5.png', 'test10.png', 'test11.png']
```

So just keep that in mind when you're working with it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir
from sys import argv
from os.path import *
print listdir(dirname(argv[1]).index(basename(argv[1]))
```

but it really means nothing, can't even imagine usecase when you need it. See `os.path` for details.

Comment: Thanks, but your code has exactly the same problems as @mgilson's - bracket is missed and it doesn't count folders.